# Visualize array in a plot with colours in different styles

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I want to visualize an array with colour plots, so I can compare many arrays with each other and see where they are similar or not. An example array would be:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

coef = np.array([7.84678e-06, -3.03161e-06, 4.1283e-06, -3.33764e-06, 8.18091e-07, 4.0515e-07, 5.03187e-06, 1.40076e-05, -0.240809, -0.0133863, 0.0479671, 0.0740471, 0.222519, 0.10136, 0.0594249, -0.103346])

plt.pcolor([coef,coef] , cmap = 'hsv' )
plt.show()
```

And get as plot:

[image]

Is there any other or better way to visualize arrays? Specially if I get a longer array with a length of 1000 or 2000 its not clearly arranged:

[image]

Comment: Linear plot: x is np.arange(`coeff.size`), y is `coeff`. In short, just `plt.plot(coeff)`

Comment: With plt.plot(coef) I just get a signal plot, like a noise signal. I need more a visualization plot like coloured bar codes

Comment: Then what you have is what you are asking for. Unless you sort or otherwise manipulate the data, you're stuck with that.

Comment: Just searching for different visualization forms